# jQuery/Javascript: insert ID into jSON object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, replace

I get the following object as a paramter via a function call from a flashMovie. So I have a simple javascript function like `savePro(info)` that is called from a flashmovie.

So I can simply `console.log(info)` and I get this.

```
{"action":"setProjectAll", "application":{"proId":"new","zoomPosition":35,"scrollerPosition":0,"language":"en","timelinePosition":0}, "clips":[]}
```

I have a variable `var id = 12` inside my js file. This variable is dynamic but it always holds a number.

How can I replace the `"proID":"new"` inside the json object with the `id` of my variable?
So I want to have …

```
{"action":"setProjectAll", "application":{"proId":12,"zoomPosition":35,"scrollerPosition":0,"language":"en","timelinePosition":0}, "clips":[]}
```

afterwards.

I have absolutely no idea how to do so?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if this is actual `JSON` text you're talking about, you'd either need to

- attempt some fancy string manipulation, or
- parse it, modify it, then stringify it

The latter would be like this...

```
var obj = JSON.parse(info);  // parse the JSON into a JavaScript object

obj.application.proId = id; // modify the object

info = JSON.stringify(obj);  // stringify it into JSON if you wanted it as JSON
```

---

If you really do not have `JSON` data, then you'd just manipulate it in the manner that you'd find in any beginner JavaScript book.

That would be the same approach as the second line of code above...

```
info.application.proId = id; // modify the object
```

Answer (score 1):

Use dot notation to access the property:

```
info.application.proId = id;
```

Side note:  JSON is a string representation used for interchange.  What it looks like you are dealing with is just a *JavaScript object*.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a "json object", you either have "json", which is a string representation of your object, or you have an "object". Assuming the latter you can set the property as follows:

```
info.application.proId = id;
```

If you have JSON you need to parse it to create an object and then set the property (and if you need it as a string turn it back to JSON afterwards):

```
info = JSON.parse(info);
info.application.proId = id;
info = JSON.stringify(info);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access properties in a JSON object using dot notation. Like this:

```
info.application.proId = id;
```